# How can I take screenshots from inside a fullscreen program?

Tags: fullscreen, screenshot

Normally, I hit my "Print Screen" key, and this wonderful thing appears.
[image]
However, I have no such luck in fullscreen programs.  Nothing happens.  No wonderful little screenshot helper, no clipboard content.

How can I take screenshots of fullscreen programs?

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to skin a cat.

In your application launcher, you should have this guy:

[image]

Turns out, he has a delay setting:

[image]

It's not ideal, but you can open this, set a sufficient delay, open your program, and when the time comes, it will successfully take a (fullscreen) screenshot of a fullscreen program.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

Try any command line tool , like scrot , in case when you're unable to switch out of that application , like DOOM3 , which grab X11 totally

e.g delay 10 seconds for a screenshot

> scrot -cd 10

or continuous screenshot using a bash script:

```
while true
do 
   scrot -cd 10
done
```

That's how i made a walk-through for Doom3 in Linux ;-P